# Apache Nutch with Lucene

Tags: apache, lucene, indexing, nutch

We have a legacy code in Lucene and as a new requirement we need to use Apache Nutch for crawling. It means that Apache Nutch should crawl content and then the existing Lucene analysers should generate indexes.

My problem is that Apache Nutch already generate indexes from which I can't generate the content. We do not want to use Nutch indexes.

Do you advise me to use another crawler or is it still possible to use Apache Nutch for this end?

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/nutch/user/107nxs32ke/best-way-to-crawl-but-not-index

Comment: Thanks for the link, I just performed everything mentioned in the link but how can I recuperate the content of what has been crawled? Because I see two types of files: index and data. All I want is to be able to run Lucene analysers on it.

Answer (score 2):

Nutch: This is the web or file crawler that will crawl through web pages or fileshares and fetch and parse the content.  It was designed to be integrated with Apache Solr so has many functions, the most uselful is passing content it has generated over to Solr, but Nutch does not do the indexing.

Solr:  Solr is a search server that will index your data for you using Lucene.  Once Nutch has passed the documents over (via http) Solr will index them and store the Lucene indexes.  There is a nice search interface allowing you to query Solr which will return the results in XML format.

Use Solr and Nutch - they were designed to work together

Check out [Setting Up Solr 4](http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html) and [Setting Up Nutch](http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/configuring-nutch-to-crawl-urls.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use solr for indexing purpose. Solr is an open-source search server based on the Lucene Java search library and easily configurable with Nutch.

Command:

- bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://solr.server:8983/solr/ -depth depth -topN topN

It will crawl seed urls list up to specified depth and index them to specified solr server. Solr internally creates lucene indexes..

Reference: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

Comment: I don't have the possibility to use SOLR for the moment, this is a constraint that I have and I have to use the existing Lucene Analysers for indexing purpose. The indexes generated by Nutch seem to be different than those of Lucene, I'm not sure if there is a way to use pure Lucene Analysers with the Nutch Segments.